# Can't select database for transaction log backup in maintenance plan

Tags: sql-server, maintenance

I am running into a problem while trying to save a transaction log database backup maintenance task:

1. Add the 'Back Up Database Task' to the maintenance plan.
2. Edit the task.
3. Select backup type: 'Transaction Log'.
4. Select any database running with Full Recovery Model.
5. Close the task.
6. Re-open the task. Notice that the database I selected is not checked anymore.

I can select all databases, all user databases, specific databases...none of them ever save. Every time I re-open the task that field is switched back to < Select one or more > option.

I've connected as user sa and I've connected with Windows Authentication. Same result. Also, I've double-checked that the databases I'm trying to backup are in Full recovery model.

I'm running SQL Server 2005 SP2 on Windows 2003 R2 SP2.

[image]

Comment: And if you run the maintenance plan backup after selecting that database, does it get backed up?

Comment: I hope this doesn't sound off, but you are actually clicking Save between steps 4 and 5 right?

Comment: @HopelessN00b: It does oddly enough.

squillman: I definitely am. :)

Comment: Well, I checked on our Server 2003/SQL 2005 server and didn't get the same results as you, like I thought I would... so I don't know what's going on.

Comment: I'd say you should apply the latest service pack to the machine running SSMS, since it sounds like a client bug and you are running 2 SP behind current.